# Views shift slightly during layout when using autolayout on iOS7, but work fine on iOS 8

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, storyboard, autolayout

I"m using autolayout for my interface. It works fine on iOS 8, but there's a strange issue on iOS 7 where ui elements shift slightly whenever subViews are laid out (which is unfortunate since this needs to happen after every interaction, because a label is updated). Most of the time, it is only a slight movement, but it is sometimes much more severe (for example, sometimes, after dismissing a modally presented view controller, a container view controller in the background view controller sometimes leaps about 20 points down, before jumping back up again on layout).
There are no errors or exceptions, and no storyboard warnings about constraints or anything like that.

Brief illustrative video (3 seconds):
https://youtu.be/ThApbmUlLEs

Comment: Seems really weird. Is there a fixed height constraint to the view that contains the number that's being entered?

Comment: No, and it still happens if I get rid of the top stuff entirely. I coloured the background of all the views I'm using to try and help debug and noticed something interesting, views that have their trailing edge constrained to the trailing edge of the super view (with constant 0, so there should be no gap) start off in the right place, but end up shifting so there's a gap: http://imgur.com/WcYETZC

Comment: Other strange behaviour that suggest something is going more seriously wrong is sometimes the buttons will jump out of the container view entirely: http://imgur.com/r0ka6Ph

Comment: I noticed in the screenshots that the green call button changed size pretty dramatically, but I'm guessing that was intentional. All I can think is to clear constraints and try setting them again very carefully. If you have a sample project you can upload I'd be happy to look if you want a second pair of eyes.